# Best way to save a set of integers

Tags: c++

Let's say I want to ask the user for some integers and then I want to do some arithmetic operations on them (like compute the mean, mode, etc...). What is the best and most efficient way to collect the data to be able to apply statistical functions to it?

Answer (score 1):

Median and mode are much easier to find from sorted data.

If the user will be typing the data, then insertion sort into an array is a great choice, because the work of the sort will be spread out over all the entries.

If the data comes from an electronic source, like a file, probably best to read it all and then sort.

No matter how you choose to process it, store it in a `std::vector` or `std::deque`, since these make efficient use of memory with good cache behavior and efficient random access.

Answer (score 1):

You can "collect the data" using a `std::istream` - specifically, either `std::cin` if you want standard input (keyboard by default, or some redirected/piped file or command output), otherwise a `std::ifstream` to read a file directly.  For example:

```
double my_double;
if (!(std::cin >> my_double))
{
    std::cerr << "unable to read and parse a double from standard input\n";
    exit(1);
}
...use my_double...
```

For storing the values... best to start with `std::vector<double>`:

```
std::vector<double> my_doubles;
my_doubles.push_back(my_double);

// add all the doubles...
double total = 0;
for (auto& d : my_doubles)
    total += d;
```

For an example of combining these things:

```
// read/store all the numbers from the current position in the input stream...
while (std::cin >> my_double)
    my_doubles.push_back(my_double);
```

You can sort the container if useful:

```
std::sort(std::begin(my_doubles), std::end(my_doubles)); // default increasing

std::sort(std::begin(my_doubles), std::end(my_doubles), // decreasing
          [](double x, double y) { return x > y; });
```

Some operations may be easier with other container types, for example - a `std::set<>` is a convenient way to keep the values sorted while rejecting duplicate values, while a `std::multiset` can store duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Boost.Accumulators](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/accumulators.html) framework.

Here's their starting example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/accumulators/accumulators.hpp>
#include <boost/accumulators/statistics/stats.hpp>
#include <boost/accumulators/statistics/mean.hpp>
#include <boost/accumulators/statistics/moment.hpp>
using namespace boost::accumulators;

int main()
{
    // Define an accumulator set for calculating the mean and the
    // 2nd moment ...
    accumulator_set<double, stats<tag::mean, tag::moment<2> > > acc;

    // push in some data ...
    acc(1.2);
    acc(2.3);
    acc(3.4);
    acc(4.5);

    // Display the results ...
    std::cout << "Mean:   " << mean(acc) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Moment: " << accumulators::moment<2>(acc) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The framework has a [plethora of accumulators](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/accumulators/user_s_guide.html#accumulators.user_s_guide.the_statistical_accumulators_library) defined, often providing both lazy and eager versions of the desired statistical operations. As you would expect, it is extensible as well.